# Joomla 4 - load joomla core

Tags: joomla, joomla4

In the Joomla 3x I have this code to load Joomla core from external script:

```
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
$rootFolder = explode(DS,dirname(__FILE__));
$currentfolderlevel = 3;
array_splice($rootFolder,-$currentfolderlevel);
$base_folder = implode(DS,$rootFolder);
if(!is_dir($base_folder.DS.'libraries'.DS.'joomla')) exit('Error: Could not loaded Joomla.');
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE',implode(DS,$rootFolder));
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );
$application  = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$application ->initialise();
$rootUri = explode('/',JURI::root(true));
array_splice($rootUri,-$currentfolderlevel);
$base_uri =   JURI::getInstance()->getScheme().'://'. JURI::getInstance()->getHost(). implode('/',$rootUri).'/';
```

But it not working in the Joomla 4x anymore. How can I load the Joomla core in J4x?

Thanks

Comment: Please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange so that you can contribute there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this code, it works.

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))))); // this may change depending on the path file.
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );
```

Thanks